# Replace a string value with NaN in pandas data frame - Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Do I have to replace the value? with NaN so you can invoke the .isnull () method. I have found several solutions but some errors are always returned. Suppose:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,?,5],[?,?,4],[?,32.1,1]])
```

and if I try:

```
pd.data.replace('?', np.nan)
```

I have:

```
     0     1  2
0  1.0   NaN  5
1  NaN   NaN  4
2  NaN  32.1  1
```

but data.isnull() returns:

```
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

Why?

Answer (score 19):

I think you forget assign back:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,'?',5],['?','?',4],['?',32.1,1]])

data = data.replace('?', np.nan)
#alternative
#data.replace('?', np.nan, inplace=True)
print (data)
     0     1  2
0  1.0   NaN  5
1  NaN   NaN  4
2  NaN  32.1  1

print (data.isnull())
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1   True   True  False
2   True  False  False
```

Answer (score 7):

```
# a dataframe with string values
dat = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'FG', 2, 4], 'b':[2, 5, 'NA', 7]})
```

[image]

Removing non numerical elements from the dataframe:

```
"Method 1 - with regex"
dat2 = dat.replace(r'^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$', np.NaN, regex=True)
dat2
```

[image]

```
"Method 2 - with pd.to_numeric"
dat3 = pd.DataFrame()
for col in dat.columns:
    dat3[col] = pd.to_numeric(dat[col], errors='coerce')
dat3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a *not* null. So you will expect to get a `False` under the `isnull` test

```
>>> data = pandas.DataFrame([[1,'?',5],['?','?',4],['?',32.1,1]])
>>> data
          0      1      2
   0  False  False  False
   1  False  False  False
   2  False  False  False
```

After you replace `?` with `NaN` the test will look much different

```
>>> data = data.replace('?', np.nan)
>>> data
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1   True   True  False
2   True  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you are doing `pd.data.replace('?', np.nan)` this action is not done in place, so you must try -

```
data = data.replace('?', np.nan)
```